# Swift Programmatic TableView Not Showing Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I created a custom table view cell and am trying to load cells with just test strings shown below. The tableview is created in code and is shown on device but the cells aren't being loaded. So I think (But I could be wrong) that there is an issue in my custom cell class or in my extensions code.

**Custom TableView Cell**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var titleView = UILabel()
    var descriptionView = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(titleView)
        addSubview(descriptionView)
        
        configureTitleView()
        configureDescriptionView()
        
        setTitleConstraints()
        setDescriptionConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func set(title: String, description: String){
        titleView.text = title
        descriptionView.text = description
    }
    
    func configureTitleView() {
        titleView.numberOfLines = 0
        titleView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
    
    func configureDescriptionView(){
        descriptionView.numberOfLines = 0
        descriptionView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
    
    
    func setTitleConstraints(){
        titleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width / 2 ).isActive = true
    }
    
    func setDescriptionConstraints(){
        descriptionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        descriptionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        descriptionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.trailingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        descriptionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        descriptionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    }

}
```

**Method called in ViewDidLoad** - This Works

```
 // MARK: - Base Table View Set UP
    private func TableViewSetUp(){

        tableView?.delegate = self
        tableView?.dataSource = self
        
        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView?.backgroundColor = .brown // Testing Only
        tableView?.rowHeight = 100
        tableView?.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        
        guard let myTableView = tableView else { return }
        view.addSubview(myTableView)
        
        // Constraints
        myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (collectionView?.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true
        myTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        myTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        myTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        
    }
```

**How Im trying to add cell info**

```
extension LogViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        
    }
}

extension LogViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        print("IN CELLFORROWAT")
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell 
        cell.set(title: "BOOO", description: "aaa")
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tableView?.delegate = self
tableView?.dataSource = self

These should be after you create your TableView in the next like

so instead of

```
private func TableViewSetUp(){
    tableView?.delegate = self
    tableView?.dataSource = self
    
    tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    tableView?.backgroundColor = .brown // Testing Only
    tableView?.rowHeight = 100
    tableView?.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

use this

```
private func TableViewSetUp(){
    tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    tableView?.delegate = self
    tableView?.dataSource = self
    tableView?.backgroundColor = .brown // Testing Only
    tableView?.rowHeight = 100
    tableView?.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```